# App to wake up WiFi periodically while on sleep

Tags: applications, wi-fi, whatsapp-messenger, automation, standby

WiFi drastically drains the battery. There is a setting to disable WiFi while the phone is on sleep. However, it's all or nothing: either you are connected all the time (and kiss good-bye to the battery) or you receive notifications from WhatsApp only when you happen to turn on your phone, maybe next week.

Is there **an app that would force the phone to connect to WiFi every, say, 10 minutes while on sleep**, for WhatsApp to check for new messages? This would both save the battery and permit receiving messages (almost) in real time.

As a workaround, maybe the app could just wake up the phone every 10 minutes, though this is a bad solution.

Preferably I would like a ready app, not a programming way of doing it -- I am not good at programming for Android.

Comment: I'd start checking with our [automation tag-wiki](/tags/automation/info) – one of those apps should be capable of doing something in this context.

Answer (score 0):

While this feature is now bundled in most customised ROMs from manufacturers, you could this achieve this with third-party tools available on Playstore.

Personally, I have used [CleverConnectivity](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gyagapen.cleverconnectivitynoads&hl=en) (no ads version) app (which comes as ad version or the pro), and if you not worried too much about ads, then the free version is sufficient for your needs.

**How does CleverConnectivity work?**

> Details of features:
>
> - Configuration of ON-OFF cycle (Time On, Time Off, Usage Interval Period)
> - Disable/Enable connectivity (Wifi/Data/Sync)
> - Enable/disable management of Data/Wifi/Sync connectivity
> - Sleep Hours: During these hours, all connectivity will desactivated one screen is OFF
> - Auto Wifi-Off: Wifi will be disabled after after a defined period if screen is OFF and no known networks are available
> - Possibility to read logs generated by the app
> - Possibility to deactivate the app while the phone is plugged. The ON-OFF cycle will resume once the phone is unplugged
> - This application will automatically turn on and off connectivity (data/wifi/sync) while screen is OFF.   You can turn on/off
>     connectivity (wifi/data/sync) everywhere in the system (settings,
>     toggles on notification bar...) and will be taken into consideration
>     by CleverConnectivity

**Screenshots:**

[image]  [image]

Comment: The app looks relevant. I will check how it works before accepting the answer. On the other hand, could you please elaborate on how I can check whether my phone has this feature bundled in the ROM -- as a user, where do I check?

Comment: OOPS no. After installation, Cleverconnectivity says "devices running Android 5+ must be rooted in order to use this app". Then it unexpectedly starts playing loud music with some ad through loudspeaker (I was in the middle of a work meeting, quite embarrassing). It's OK when a free app shows ads _to me_, but it's absolutely unacceptable when it attacks me by playing sounds to the loudspeaker (!) without even warning me. Uninstalling this malware immediately! So sorry, so far I cannot yet accept this answer.

Comment: I apologise for the embarassment, however so far this was one of the most reliable solutions I worked with, you can still block its internet connectivity as use it as if its offline...goodluck :)

Comment: Ads are no problem, one can pay. But this solution is for rooted phones. Though I did not specify this in the question, but I think most lay users like me have unrooted phones. Any idea for an unrooted phone? Meanwhile I searched too, but did not yet find anything.

Comment: FYI, looks like this specific no-ads version is not available on the Play Store anymore (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before). I could only find [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gyagapen.cleverconnectivity) instead.